# In Python, how to specify argument is a list where all elements have the same type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

quick question...

I'm trying to do something like this:

```py
from typing import List


def reverse_list(original: List) -> List:
    return original[::-1]
```

I want to get a warning if I pass in something like this: `[1, 3, "a", 10]`, because not all elements have the same type.

I would like to accept `["c", "a", "b"]` or `[1, 8, 2]`—and have Python know that the return value will be a list of strings or a list of ints.

Is this doable? I get the feeling it is not.

Thanks!

Comment: See if this website helps you - https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what I came up with

```py
def check_if_mix(list_: List):
    first_type = type(list_[0])
    return any(not isinstance(i, first_type) for i in list_)

check_if_mix([1,2,3])
>>>False

check_if_mix([1,2,"a"])
>>>True
```

So if you want to get warned in case there are mixed types, the simplest way would be to check this before reversing the list:

```py
def reverse_list(original: List) -> List:
    if check_if_mix(original):
        print('WARNING: list contains mixed types')
    return original[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you Auss, that's a solution with better performance as well—appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do the test yourself

```py
from typing import List
import warnings

def sameType(a, b):
 return type(a) == type(b)

def allSameType(aList):
 allZip = zip(aList, aList[1:])
 return all([sameType(a,b) for a,b in allZip])

def reverse_list(original: List) -> List:
    if not allSameType(original):
        warnings.warn('Not all the items in your list are the same type')
    return original[::-1]
```

Change `type(a) == type(b)` to `isinstance(a, b)` if you believe inherited classes are the same type as their ancestors.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I figured it wasn't possible—probably an infrequent use case. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static type checker like mypy to check your program, the correct thing to do is to make your function a [*generic function*](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-functions):

```
from typing import List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def reverse_list(original: List[T]) -> List[T]:
    return original[::-1]
```

That TypeVar is a "placeholder" -- the typechecker will understand that if we pass in a `List[str]` into this function, that `T` must be type `str`. Therefore, it'll conclude the output type must also be a `List[str]` after completing the substitution.

Note that this solution is even more efficient then the other ones, since there's no runtime checking happening at all -- the Python interpreter completely ignores type hints. The static type checker will verify the correctness of the program instead.

(This is also potentially a downside -- you'll need to add accurate type hints to the large bulk of your program before type checking starts to become an effective way of guarding against bugs, and doing that is not always feasible.)

Comment: But you can pass `Union[str, int]` to it, right? And then `T` would be the union, so it doesn't do what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this. Iterate over every element in the list and raise an error if it's not an integer.

```
from typing import List

def reverse_list(original: List) -> List:
    for element in original:
        if not isinstance(element, int):
            raise TypeError("Element of the list: " + element + " is not an integer.")
    return original[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you Rafal, not what the question asked though!

Comment: heh, that's true :D